# Are the ordinates of the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ uniformly distributed around the mid points of Gram point intervals they can be mapped to?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, gaussian, rootfinding

Let $\rho_n$ be the $n$-th non-trivial zero of $\zeta(s)$ and $z_n = \Im(\rho_n)$ with $z_n > 0$ and $z_{n+1} \ge z_n$.

A well known method to establish that all $\rho$s reside on the critical line ($\Re(\rho)=\frac12)$ up to a certain height $T$, is to make use of the regularly distributed and easy to compute [Gram points](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GramPoint.html) ($g_n$).

The process boils down to assuring that each Gram point interval $[g_n,g_{n+1})$ contains only a single $z$. Heuristics show this is already the case for most intervals, however it is also known to fail infinitely often resulting in empty intervals or intervals containing multiple $z$ (i.e. violations of [Gram's law](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GramsLaw.html) and [Rosser's rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RossersRule.html)).

Failures will typically be induced when larger swings in the $Z(t)$-function occur, where $Z(t) = e^{i\Theta(t)} \zeta\left(\frac12 + it\right)$ and $\Theta(t)$ is the [Riemann-Siegel Theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_theta_function). Some accounting is then required to ensure there are as many $z$ as intervals in a Gram block with 'bad' Gram points. Morally this process is equivalent to mapping each 'wrongly' located $z$ to its unique interval.

So, when $Z(t)$ oscillates rather 'calmly', a $z$ will typically reside not too far from the middle of its Gram point interval. However, when oscillations of $Z(t)$ become more 'fierce' in amplitude, the $z$ will be pushed more towards the edges of their intervals or even hop into the neighbouring intervals.

With this in mind, we could compute how far ($=d_n$) each $z_n$ has been 'pushed' away from the mid point of the interval it 'belongs to'. This could be done as follows (*note:* the index of a Gram point $g_n$ starts at $-1$ and for $z$ at $1$):

$$d_n = z_n - \frac{g_{n-2}+g_{n-1}}{2}$$

The picture below aims to visualise the process and how $d_n$ is computed for real data around the first [Lehmer pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_pair). (*note:* the legend of the red line should be: $\Im\left( e^{(i\sin(\Theta(t))}\right)$)

[image]

The next graphs show the normalised histograms of the differences $d_n$ for increasing ranges of $n$.

[image]

**Question:**

The shape of the distribution seems to become increasingly 'normal' for higher $n$. Could this indeed be the case and if so, is there a logical explanation for this phenomenon?

Here is the $d_n$-data for [$n=1..999999$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oiynVgJB0scgVuJoUK_4x258FS1mh5N8/view?usp=sharing).

**ADDED 1:**

Since, on average, the densities of $z_n$ and $g_n$ increase when we go up the critical line, the variances of the distributions shown above will become smaller and their peaks higher. This can be normalised as follows:

$$d_n^* = z_n \log(z_n) - \frac{g_{n-2}+g_{n-1}}{2}\log\left(\frac{g_{n-2}+g_{n-1}}{2}\right)$$

Here is the $d_n^*$-data for [$n=1..999999$](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HNViOotgugGgNVrX61gQQ84kQJXiibWJ/view?usp=sharing).

A Normal distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=2.65$ then already provides a pretty decent visual fit (red line).

[image]

**ADDED 2:**

Here is the distribution of the first 100 mln $d_n^*$ (blue dots). The red line is a Normal distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=2.71$.

[image]

The real data have a $\mu=-5.301\cdot 10^{-8}$ and $\sigma=2.642$. The fit with the Normal distribution clearly gets weaker in the tails. I do expect this to improve for larger $n$, since the "turmoil" in $Z(t)$ is expected to increase thereby inducing a relatively higher proportion of larger deviations $d_n^*$.

A Gram point is defined as the $t$ where $\Theta(t)=k\pi$ (i.e. where $\Im\left(\zeta(\frac12+it)\right)=0, t\ne z$). I realised that the mid point of the Gram interval (calculated as a simple average above), quickly converges to the $t$ where $\Theta(t)=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ (i.e. where $\Re\left(\zeta(\frac12+it)\right)=0, t\ne z$). Let's label these points as $\hat{g}_n$.

My question is then equivalent to: "Is $\hat{d}_n=z_n -\hat{g}_{n-2}$ uniformly distributed?" or in other words: "Is the difference between 'paired' zeros of $\Re\zeta(\frac12+it)$ uniformly distributed?".

Comment: Maybe you can find relevant results about some kind of "normal distribution of critical zeros related quantities" in Selberg's collected papers.

Comment: Not what you ask for, but somewhat related and maybe interesting for you (if you don't know it already): Arias de Reyna, J.: On the distribution (mod 1) of the normalized zeros of the Riemann zeta-function. J. Number Theory 153 (2015), 37–53. That paper is not about the distance between the zero and the Gram point it "belongs to", but about the relative location of the zero with respect to the Gram points between which it is actually located.

Comment: @Kurisuto Asutora Thanks for the useful link! Arias de Reyna indeed follows a related but different approach. The uniformity of the resulting distributions (for $n=1..2mln$) also appears to be a bit less strong, but this is based on inspecting the visuals only. An intriguing sentence is his paper I find: "In a non published report, Odlyzko [14, p. 60] conjectured that the ordinates of the zeros $z_n$ are not related to the Gram points for $z_n$ large". This conjecture seems to contradict my observations above.

Comment: Odlyzko's unpublished paper is at http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/unpublished/zeta.10to20.1992.pdf

Comment: Is there a rationale for $\sigma=2.65$?  I observe that the $10^7$-th zero occurs at height $T=4.99238\cdot 10^6$, and $\log \log T=2.73589$.

Comment: @Stopple. Unfortunately I have no rationale for the $\sigma = 2.65$, it is just the value I picked that gave the best visual fit with the relative distribution of the first $10^6$-th $d_n^*$. For higher $n$ this could get closer to your value (I had even hoped that $\sigma = e$ for a moment ;-) ).

Comment: Concerning "Could this indeed be the case and if so, is there a logical explanation for this phenomenon?": For comparison, you could study a similar statistic for randomly generated points instead of the zeta zeros. For example, take a Poisson process with intensity one, which gives you (random) points $x_1,x_2,...$, and then look at the distribution of difference $x_n - n,~1 \leq n \leq N$ (suitably normalized).

Comment: @Kurisuto Asutora Apologies for my slow response, just back from holidays. I have checked the distributions for the edges of the intervals i.e. $z_n-g_{n-1}$ and $z_n-g_{n-2}$ and as expected their means shift and they become skewed. Have also tried the Poisson process with $\lambda=1$ and produced sample paths for the first 1 mln steps $x_n$. Then computed the differences $x_n-n$ and the associated Histograms. The resulting distributions seem quite chaotic and are far from normal.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the distribution that you obtain for the points coming from the Poisson process? (I am traveling and don't have a computer with me to try to experiment myself).

Comment: PS: I don't understand the last two sentences in your post. What do they mean? (You mean "normally distributed instead of "uniformly distributed"?)

Comment: @Kurisuto Asutora The Maple code used is: J := PoissonProcess(1.0); A := SamplePath(J(t), t = 1 .. 10000, timesteps = 10000, replications = 1); L := [seq(A(x) - x, x = 1 .. 10000)]; Histogram(L, color = "blue", bincount = 200, frequencyscale = relative, style = polygon, symbolsize = 1, range = -100 .. 100); Running this, results (for instance) in the following plot: https://ibb.co/W32L0Bj. Not sure wether I have done this correctly, but the first column of this picture is the distribution we're after https://ibb.co/6DW60NS . To your PS, I indeed meant 'normally distributed'.